# How do I get the Girdle of Masculinity/Femininity in Baldur's Gate 2?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

on the wikia for the [Girdle of Masculinity/Femininity](http://baldursgate.wikia.com/wiki/Girdle_of_Masculinity/Femininity) it says

> The Girdle of Masculinity/Femininity can be found on the body of the girdle ogre in the Coast Way

and the Categories for that page include both Enhanced Editions of Baldur's Gate. yet looking at the [world maps](http://baldursgate.wikia.com/wiki/World_Map) it seems Baldur's Gate 2 is different.

I haven't played Baldur's Gate 2 yet and I've only know that there is a character import from the first game to the second because I have seen this talked about when talking about Duel Classing, as such so I don't know whether I can return to the Baldur's Gate 1 World Map in the second game or not or whether I keep my inventory when I import my character.

So I am wondering, how do I get the Girdle of Masculinity/Femininity in Baldur's Gate 2?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to legitimately acquire the Girdle of Masculinity/Femininty in Baldur's Gate 2. It isn't available in game, and most items cannot be imported as the start of Shadows of Amn takes your inventory.

It is still available in the game files, so either spawning it with console commands (BELT05) or a save game editor such as [EEKeeper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eekeeper/) can add it to your game.